# How to set referenced document _id optional in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a product `schema` in node.js server like this

```js
export var Product = mongoose.model(
    "product",
    new Schema({
        name: String,
        brand: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "brand" },
        colors: [String],
        sizes: [String],
        description: String,
        thumnbail: String,
        images: [String],
        thumnbnailImage: String,
        price: Number,
        quantity: Number,
        discount: Number,
        category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "category" },
        createdAt: String,
        updatedAt: String,
        isActive: { type: Boolean, default: true }
    })
);
```

In this `schema` i referenced `brand` collection. But it's not necessary for user to give `brand` for adding `product` from client side. Now when i am trying to add `product` in which i am not giving `brand`'s `_id` because it's optional so `node.js` throws an error like this

```
product validation failed: brand: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "" at path "brand"
```

how can i make `_id` for brand in `product` document make an optional field so that if user will not give `brand`'s `_id` so my server will not give an error like this?

Comment: In mongoose, usually every field is optional, unless you specify `required:true`, I think here you're trying to send `brand:''` in input that means you're actually having brand field in document, I guess you need to have a condition here, if you really need it empty string in some documents !!

Comment: so what should i send in `brand` from client side if there will be no brand for product?

Comment: either you can actually have a validator func in schema or did you try entirely removing brand field in input object ? So do you want it to be empty string in a document if you don't have a brand ??

Comment: yes i tried by deleting brand field completely if there will be no brand id and it worked for me thanks :) post your solution if you want , i will accept that

Comment: So, don't you need that field at all in document or do you need it empty string when you don't have brand value for a user ? Based on that we can enhance your code to make it work having `brand:''`

Comment: i need to remove brand if brand's field will be equal to `` on client side. So i delete brand field from `product` object when `brand`'s `_id` will not be there and if there will be any `_id` for any brand then i am adding `brand`'s `_id` field in my `product` object

Comment: I have a similar use case where the brand value can be an actual brand or may be a string value like `*` to denote a wild entry. Any suggestions on how this may be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoose, usually every field is optional, unless you specify `required:true`.

From this error :

> Cast to ObjectID failed for value "" at path "brand"

It seems to be you're trying to send `brand:''` in input that means you're actually having brand field in document, So you're getting `MongooseError`, You need to have a validation function here, if you really need it empty string in some documents or you can remove brand field(when it's not equal to `ObjectId()`) from input object before sending it to db operation.